# Upload file with PhantomJS to a Dropzone

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

My code for uploading a file is this:

```
var uploadEl = document.getElementById("upload"); // div
page.upload(uploadEl, 'C:/temp/1.JPG');
```

This actually hangs, so my question is, what is the proper way to upload a file to a dropzone with PhantomJS?

*The way a user manually upload a file is like a user clicks the upload div browser opens a native File upload select, the user selects the file and hits the Open button and the website triggers the upload via ajax.*

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to upload files in PhantomJS is this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');
```

It should also work for Dropzone, because `uploadFile` method behaves as if a user picked a file with a file dialog:

> This function is used to automate the upload of a file, which is usually handled with a file dialog in a traditional browser. Since there is no dialog in this headless mode, such an upload mechanism is handled via this special function instead.

Source: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html

Comment: The selector selects an input with attribute "name" equals "image", what if the element is just a div

Comment: So your code will throw `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'page.upload('input[name=image]', 'C:/temp/1.JPG')')`